# How to properly configure the new Anaconda 2.1 in PyCharm 3.4?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pycharm, interpreter, anaconda

I recently updated to **Anaconda to 2.1.** For some reason, **Pycharm 3.4** was previously configured with **E.Canopy - Python 2.7.6.** I did not know that, so yesterday I uninstalled Canopy. Now when I open PyCharm I get:

```
Invalid Python interpreter selected for the project
```

So [I followed the instructions](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/configuring-available-python-interpreters.html) to configure the appropriate interpreter: Anaconda. However the configuration fails. I get:

```
 11:44:38 AM Some skeletons failed to generate: 1 module failed in 1 interpreter. Details... 

 Failed Modules

 **Python 2.7.7**

 dde

 Generation of skeletons for the modules above will be tried again when modules are updated or a  
 new version of generator is available
```

So it seems there's a conflict because of the different Python Versions....How can I solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happend to me... I just repeated the update process. hope this helps.